# How does one get this equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How does $\dfrac {3} {n(n+2)}={\dfrac{1}{ 2}} (\dfrac{3}{n} - {\dfrac{3}{n+2}})$?

Which rule is used here to get this equation? $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: Partial fraction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you familiar with partial fractions decomposition? Partial fractions decomposition says we can rewrite $\frac{3}{n(n+2)}$ as $\frac{A}{n} + \frac{B}{n+2}$ for some $A, B$.

To find $A$, and $B$, we cross multiply and compare coefficients on terms of equal degree; that is:

$A(n+2) + B(n) = 3 + 0*n$

Hence, we obtain the following linear system:

$A + B = 0$

$2A = 3$

Can you solve for $A$ and $B$ from here?

Comment: I guess I learned something new. thank-you.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{3}{n(n+2)}=\dfrac{A}{n+2}+\dfrac{B}{n}$

$\dfrac{An+B(n+2)}{n(n+2)}$ , $An+B(n+2)=3$, Plug $n=-2$ to get $A$ and $n=0$, to get $B$. You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction).

Answer (score 1):

calculate $A$ and $B$ by this rule. $n A+(n+2)B=3$ then $n (A+B) +2B=3$, so $(A+B)=0$ and $2B=3$, so $B=3/2$, $A=-3/2$, now put $A$ and $B$ in equation $\frac{3}{n(n+2)}=\frac{A}{n+2}+\frac{B}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

General rule:

$$\frac1{(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac1{a-b}\left(\frac1{x-a}-\frac1{x-b}\right)\;,\;\;a\neq b$$

and if you want it even prettier just take care $\,a>b\,$ . In your case, $\,a=0\;,\;b=-2\,$ , so

$$\frac1{n(n+2)}=\frac12\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the equation by multiplying both sides with the nonzero number $n(n+2)$ and then simplifying.